# Javascript: Why are getters used over methods?

Tags: javascript, methods, getter

So I'm wondering what the difference is between methods and getters?

Reading the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Description):

> Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a
>   dynamically computed value, or you may want to reflect the status of
>   an internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method
>   calls

But don't they achieve the same thing? Why is one better than the other?

Why is saying:

```
var obj = {
    log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    get latest() {
    if (this.log.length == 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
}

console.log(obj.latest);
```

Sometimes preferable to just having a latest() method and calling obj.latest(). If the code is run in both cases, then what's the point? Aren't they both dynamic?

The documentation [also reads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters):

> Getters give you a way to define a property of an object, but they do
>   not calculate the property's value until it is accessed.

What exactly is the difference between 'accessed' and 'called'? A method isn't run until it's called, just as a property isn't accessed until its included? So where does the significance lie?

Comment: Consider a case where the object and the property name are combined dynamically, with code making the access expecting to simply access the value of the property via the name it's been given. The ability to implement a property as a "covert" function call means that such code can be written without any special need to figure out whether a property value should be accessed as a function call or as a simple property.

Comment: This is going to end up being an opinion based question.  Some developers detest computed properties because they obfuscate logic, some love them for the ease of use.

Comment: @zero298 well I sort-of agree, although like the practice or not the rationale for it can be described objectively.

Comment: I do think that you might have a much better question if you narrow your focus to that last paragraph: *"What exactly is the difference between 'accessed' and 'called'? A method isn't run until it's called, just as a property isn't accessed until its included? So where does the significance lie?"*.

Comment: According to information on the `use strict` directive, seems it is used for the security purpose of preventing assignment to an attribute of that name. see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: Thank you all for weighing in on this, I feel like I have a bit better of a handle on things now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, the following is an opinion.

A getter is for retrieving the value of a specific property, and it allows your object to have dynamic properties based on the value of other properties but otherwise behave just as you would expect properties to behave. The getter allows you to define a method that is called when you access that property, even though you access it with normal object property accessors, `myObject.dynamicProp` and `myObject['dynamicProp']`.

Getters are provided for exactly that purpose. If that's the intent of the method you are writing, then use the getter syntax.

Methods exist to do other things that are verbal, action oriented, and not to simply return some property of the object you're writing.

You can always write a method to be a getter, but why?

So it depends on your intent. Getters specify intent, and if your intent is to provide a dynamic property that behaves just like an object property then use a getter over a method.

Hope that helps!

**Updated**:

While there is technical nuance to be understood here, and though I've leaned toward using the getters above, I'd say, after further reflection, that the approach you wish to take is up to you based on:

(1) Do you want to use normal accessors to access this property? Are you ok with dynamic properties that hide some logic? (They don't really 'hide' the logic per se, but they look just like normal props to the caller). Then use the `get()`.

(2) Do you want to make it obvious and more readable that your property is dynamic? Are you doing things besides just computing a dynamic property based on the current values of existing properties of this object? Are you ok with having to call the method explicitly? Then use a method, e.g. `getLatest()`.

Comment: i think it's important to take into account the documentation for the `set` keyword. It sheds a bit of light on the whole thing. Seems that get and set intercept attempts to assign or access what would be an attribute of that name, without requiring a prior assignment of that attribute. While functionally, they dont provide anything different than methods + attributes combined, it allows a kind of shorthand for a specific scenario. Why they would add it is still in question. This seems to be relevant https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: Sure, that's a great point. Perhaps elucidate that understanding with another good answer? Sometimes, especially, this kind of question is well served by a couple of answers.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, and a good point. Added my contribution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `Object.defineProperty()` on [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

> Property descriptors present in objects come in two main flavors: data
>   descriptors and accessor descriptors. A data descriptor is a property
>   that has a value, which may or may not be writable. An accessor
>   descriptor is a property described by a getter-setter pair of
>   functions. A descriptor must be one of these two flavors; it cannot be
>   both.
>
> Both data and accessor descriptors are objects. They share the
>   following optional keys:
>
> **configurable** true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object. Defaults to false.
>
> **enumerable** true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. Defaults to false.
>
> A data descriptor also has the following optional keys:
>
> **value** The value associated with the property. Can be any valid JavaScript value (number, object, function, etc). Defaults to undefined.
>
> **writable** true if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator. Defaults to false.
>
> An accessor descriptor also has the following optional keys:
>
> **get** A function which serves as a getter for the property, or undefined if there is no getter. When the property is accessed, this function is called without arguments and with this set to the object through which the property is accessed (this may not be the object on which the property is defined due to inheritance). The return value will be used as the value of the property. Defaults to undefined.
>
> **set** A function which serves as a setter for the property, or undefined if there is no setter. When the property is assigned to, this function is called with one argument (the value being assigned to the property) and with this set to the object through which the property is assigned. Defaults to undefined.
>
> If a descriptor has neither of value, writable, get and set
>   keys, it is treated as a data descriptor. If a descriptor has both
>   value or writable and get or set keys, an exception is thrown.

This indicates that `get` and `set` intercept access calls and assignment calls respectively.

A very good example (and description) [here](https://javascriptplayground.com/es5-getters-setters/) points out a clear example of when this is useful.

Take a case where you have the first and last name on a person, with the common need for the full name.

```
person.setLastName('Smith');
person.setFirstName('Jimmy');
person.getFullName(); // Jimmy Smith
```

Using the `get` and `set` keys, gives you the option of declaring the object like so:

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'Jimmy',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set fullName (name) {
        var words = name.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0] || '';
        this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
}
```

and assigning it, and accessing it like so:

```
person.fullName = 'Jack Franklin';
console.log(person.firstName); // Jack
console.log(person.lastName) // Franklin
console.log(person.fullName) // Jack Franklin
```

This allows the developer to interact with fullname, without accidentally leaving firstname or lastname unassigned or improperly assigned.

Lastly,

The `use strict` directive will enforce read and write attempts to attributes defined through `get` or `set` accordingly. See [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp).

```
"use strict";
var obj = {get x() {return 0} };

obj.x = 3.14;            // This will cause an error
```